# Can you obtain your current Mirror API Quota usage programmatically?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Is there a way to programmatically obtain the Mirror API usage of an explorer developer account?

I would like to more gracefully degrade services when a 403 error becomes imminent.

Thanks!

If any explorers are having luck counting usage on their end and find it to be reliable I would be open to tips in that direction, especially with respect to what GMT time the 1000 counter resets each day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API for Google API Console quotas. Your best bet is to track this yourself by counting each outbound request on your system.

Comment: Do you know what time the clock resets each day/night (I already keep track, but don't know how to segment the days)

Comment: They reset at midnight Pacific time.